# Why does Ubuntu comes with two firewalls by default?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I realised Ubuntu comes with two firewalls by default `iptables` and `ufw`. But why? I mean running more than one software firewall on one computer can be bad because it can cause conflicts. I don't understand why it has two by default - won't that be bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't come with two firewalls. From [the Ubuntu wiki page on ufw](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) (sic):

> The Uncomplicated Firewall (`ufw`) is a frontend for `iptables` and is
>   particularly well-suited for host-based firewalls. ufw provides a
>   framework for managing `netfilter`, as well as a command-line interface
>   for manipulating the firewall. `ufw` aims to provide an easy to use
>   interface for people unfamiliar with firewall concepts, while at the
>   same time simplifies complicated `iptables` commands to help an
>   adminstrator who knows what he or she is doing. `ufw` is an upstream for
>   other distributions and graphical frontends.

One is a frontend to the other. There is only one firewall.

Comment: So ufw is just a easier way to use iptables.

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: If you find it easier, sure.

Comment: But if I have gufw will I have to remove ufw?

Comment: Why do you think that? O.o

Answer (score 0):

Both ufw, gufw, and a number of alternate "frontends" all create configuration for iptables. They aren't firewalls, they are config editors for the firewall.

They work only "work" when you open them and edit the options. After you "save" the config IPTables just applies the changes and starts working using the new config, but it really doesn't matter what you use to load or edit the config. Various config editors may "conflict" in that if you created a setup in one, another may fail to load it properly and you will be editing it "from scratch/from default" and not from "currently active", and applying it will override the current one instead of merging with it. But otherwise, IPTables doesn't care what creates its config, and config editors don't care what other config editors are next to them.